# OS X equivalent of --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files

Tags: c++, linux, macos, clang++

On Linux (CentOS) I have occasionally used `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` when building a test application that only depends on parts of some object files even though the full dependency would require a lot more object files to be included. The point is that I know by design any unresolved symbols are never encountered when running the test application (otherwise it should just crash).

On OS X, I found similar options `-Wl,-undefined,suppress (or warning, dynamic_lookup),-flat_namespace` which allowed me to build the binary, but it failed at run time complaining about `dyld: Symbol not found: ...` even though the missing symbols are never used during the run (the same application runs perfectly fine on CentOS).

Is there something else to force the application to run (till it crashes if ever an unresolved symbol is encountered) like on Linux?